# When is it safe to retrieve image height in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiimageview, autolayout

I've got a table cell. Within it I've got an image that has a height constraint of 25% of the screen size.

When is the proper time to retrieve the image height using

```
imageView.frame.height
```

to make sure that it has been resized according to the constraint? In general i am a little confused as to when the time to retrieve the element heights (images, labels ) is in the lifecycle. I need this information to add up with all the other element heights for a cell so i can tell a table what the row size is using the **heightForRow** method.

*P.S: I cannot use **UITableViewAutomaticDimension** as one of the elements is a webview and i can only retrieve its height after the webview delegate method completes and has loaded a webpage.*

Comment: UITableViewAutomaticDimension works better, all other method will not work in your case else `viewDidLayoutSubViews` is best time to get actual size of any view

Comment: I dont think i can use UITableViewAutomaticDimension since one of the elements used is a webview which will take some time to load and since i want it to fit entirely height-wise i need to retrieve its height one its done loading.

Comment: cell will expend accordingly when data loading is finished if you set constraint correctly

Comment: What is correctly? I ve set the constraint in all 4 directions but the webview just takes up limited space and scrolls. I've tried making it fittosize but that only zoomed out the webview itself and everything looked tiny.

Comment: You can use `override func webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)aWebView {}` and set calculate height and set height constraint programmatically this will solve your problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using autolayotus, you can get `imageView` or any other `UIElements` frames in `viewDidLayoutSubViews` or in `viewDidAppear`. These life cycle methods will be called while/after applying constraints.

Comment: In my case i am within a table cell so i'm assuming the equivalent of 'viewDidLayoutSubviews here is 'layoutSubviews' which i assume eventually will return the final height value for each element.

To expand a bit, what should the original tablecell height be set to ( since initially i dont know what it would be before measuring the image the label and the webview ) ? I ve found that if you set it too something too smal ( e.g 40 ) then the layouting wont happen properly and you wont ever get the required image size.Is it too hamfisted to set it to a big value like 1000 for example?

Thanks

Comment: If you want to get value in middle of the coding. Before accessing image.frame you can call setNeedsUpdateConstraints to update the constraints to latest

Comment: and that would happen serially? Meaning in the next line of code i will have the proper height guaranteed 100%?

Comment: I can guarantee about that in life cycle methods. Mostly this will give height if you set all constraints correct. If that won't work let me know.

Comment: The problem with using the lifecycle methods is the cell method layoutSubviews seems to be called everytime i reload the controller's table. And i need to be reloading the controller's table with the calculated height that i'm getting through the layoutSubview method...

So this just goes on and on..

Sorry for being annoying.

Comment: Understood. Then reloading table view only once in viewDidAppear will be better approach i think

Answer (score 0):

You can always subclass UIImageView and override methods setFrame and setBounds to met your needs.